# Invalid Address format - Etherscan.io APIs problem

Tags: web3js, javascript, etherscan, nodejs, api-design

I have download list of verified open source contract addresses's list and loaded into addresses[]. Now I want to download sourcecode/ABIs etc... of that contracts. Although, i have called setTimeOut between each API call to avoid excessive calls, but still could not be succeeded.

**Here is my code;** . If i download **one contract**, then this code has no problem

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { window } = new jsdom.JSDOM(`...`);
var $ = require("jquery")(window);

var data = fs.readFileSync('./osContracts/list.csv', 'utf8'); 

myJData = csvToJSON(data);

var addresses = [];

for(i=0; i<myJData.length-1; i++)
{
addresses[i] = myJData[i].ContractAddress;
}

for(i=0; i<addresses.length; i++){
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address='+addresses[i]+'&apikey=QTUXRX1X2T.....', function (adData) {
    console.log(adData.result)          
        });
    }, 5500 * i)

}
```

**Here is my error:**

```
Invalid Address format
Invalid Address format
Invalid Address format..........................................
```

**UPDATE**:
the value of addresses

```
[  
  '0x2699fc3753b1036534feb3be8704c9c5e3262606',
  '0x5a3b8896d90bf4e656d35370d6b2ab9613a854d1',
  '0xb215bf00e18825667f696833d13368092cf62e66',
  '0x213a22d873e02269ac45c094c0655a09eaa22c3a',
  '0x67d764d948408a4f01dec1623c4a42275acddb24',

...2979 more items
]
```

and i can get the the result with their values, but only for one contract
**UPDATE1.**
One Contract means... anyone from my addresses[].... not only one...

Comment: Well... Has it not occurred to you that sharing the value of `addresses[i]` with us might be relevant in this case???

Comment: i have update my question with your requisite information, please have a look..

Comment: Tried the first address with my API key, and it's working. Maybe your API key is wrong. Maybe one of the other addresses is wrong. Can you check which address actually leads to this error?

Comment: Ahh, I now see your bottom line - `and i can get the the result with their values, but only for one contract`, and the question is: Has it not occurred to you that sharing the address of that contract with us might be relevant in this case???

Comment: BTW, I was able to get it correctly for the first two contracts.

Comment: Has it not occurred to you that sharing the address of that contract with us might be relevant in this case ??? what does it means ... i have shared with you.. i said if i want to access any contract by giving its address (from my addresses[]) then i can get all things (of result, sourcecode, ABI, compilerversion, etc.) ... but when i do loop and and try to access result data (within a loop), only then i get mentioned error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `i` is already equal to `addresses.length` when your timeout callbacks are being executed.  Should be:

```js
for(i=0; i<addresses.length; i++){
  const index = i; // This will not change!
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address='+addresses[index]+'&apikey=QTUXRX1X2T.....', function (adData) {
console.log(adData.result)          
      });
  }, 5500 * i)

}
```

or, how I would rewrite it:

```js
addresses.forEach (
  (address, index) => setTimeout (
    () => $.getJSON (
      'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address=' +
        address +
        '&apikey=QTUXRX1X2T.....',
      adData => console.log (adData.result)),
    5500 * index));
```

Comment: thanks a lot ... always you save my head from burning....

Comment: your code works for me to print results... but when i want to write that result into a file then it gives another type of error ... Should I post into another question or update this Question? ...

Comment: sorry, it works for data.result... But it does not work for if i want to access some selected component of data.result[index].ContractName ... it print the First contract name, then  print undefined for the rest contracts.

Comment: Just log the whole result object via `console.log ("%o", adData)` and you will see what is wrong.

Comment: OK now i would put all details into another question , which will be my last question on this topic..

Comment: i have write all details about errors, here .... https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78047/error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-contractname-of-undefined