# Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'ContractName' of undefined]

Tags: javascript, etherscan, nodejs, api-design

I am trying to get source of open source verified contracts and write into a file at my local folder. I could write only one file (of first address) but for the rest i am facing captioned error. Please **note** that I have download list of verified open source contract addresses's list and loaded into addresses[]. I had also verified that array (`addresses[]`) has valid addresses and i can access source code by using these addressess (**individually**) , after that i can write that sourcecode into my file/folder. But the same process gives error, if executed in loop.

**Here is my code;**

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('./osContracts/list.csv', 'utf8'); 
myJData = csvJSON(data);
var addresses = [];

for(i=0; i<myJData.length-1; i++)
{
addresses[i] = myJData[i].ContractAddress;
}

for(i=0; i<addresses.length; i++){
  const index = i;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address='+addresses[index]+'&apikey=QTUXRX1........', function (adData) {

    console.log("%o", adData) // this line shows output given below
    data = adData.result[index];

    contractName = data.ContractName; // for first address its OK, if adresses are given one by one then still its OK, but for loop its not OK...

    compVersion = data.CompilerVersion;
    sourceCode = data.SourceCode;

      fs.writeFile('./openSourceContracts/'+contractName+'.sol', sourceCode, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Saved! contract'); // shows output Saved! contract... for the first contract only 
        });

    });
  }, 1500 * index)

}
```

**Here is my error;**

```
{
  status: '1',
  message: 'OK',
  result: [
    {
     ...........................
        },
    [length]: 1
  ]
}
Saved! contract
{
  status: '1',
  message: 'OK',
  result: [
    {.......................
       },
    [length]: 1
  ]
}
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'ContractName' of undefined]
    at reportException (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\runtime-script-errors.js:62:24)
    at innerInvokeEventListeners (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:332:9)
    at invokeEventListeners (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:267:3)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTargetImpl._dispatch (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:214:9)
    at fireAnEvent (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\events.js:17:36)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:936:7)
    at Request.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
    at Gunzip.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) TypeError: Cannot read property 'ContractName' of undefined
    at Object.success (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\deploy - 2Copy.js:35:25)
    at fire (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:3291:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:3421:7)
    at done (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:9533:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:9785:9)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\create-event-accessor.js:33:32)
    at innerInvokeEventListeners (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:316:27)
    at invokeEventListeners (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:267:3)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTargetImpl._dispatch (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:214:9)
    at fireAnEvent (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\events.js:17:36)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:936:7)
    at Request.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
    at Gunzip.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
{
  status: '1',
  message: 'OK',
  result: [
    {
      ............ },
    [length]: 1
  ]
}
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'ContractName' of undefined]
    at reportException (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\runtime-script-errors.js:62:24)
    at innerInvokeEventListeners (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:332:9)
    at invokeEventListeners (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:267:3)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTargetImpl._dispatch (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:214:9)
    at fireAnEvent (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\events.js:17:36)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:936:7)
    at Request.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
    at Gunzip.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) TypeError: Cannot read property 'ContractName' of undefined
    at Object.success (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\deploy - 2Copy.js:35:25)
    at fire (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:3291:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:3421:7)
    at done (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:9533:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:9785:9)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\create-event-accessor.js:33:32)
    at innerInvokeEventListeners (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:316:27)
    at invokeEventListeners (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:267:3)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTargetImpl._dispatch (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:214:9)
    at fireAnEvent (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\events.js:17:36)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:936:7)
    at Request.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
    at Gunzip.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
```

**UPDATE**: 
the output of  `console.log("%o", adData)` is here below;

```
    {
      status: '1',
      message: 'OK',
      result: [
        {
          SourceCode: 'pragma solidity ^0.4.21;\r\n' +
            '
            '   }\r\n' +
            '}',
          ABI: '[.........']',
          ContractName: 'StandardToken',
          CompilerVersion: 'v0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c',
          OptimizationUsed: '0',
          Runs: '200',
          ConstructorArguments: '',
          Library: '',
          LicenseType: 'MIT',
          SwarmSource: 'bzzr://733f48b35626656299ada06fbcf14c46b5bd2c9d03fd05b8ab9767016fcb02d2'
        },
    [length]: 1
  ]
}
```

output of  `console.log(Object.keys(adData.result))` is `[ '0' ]`

Comment: Your error implies that `data == undefined`, which implies that `adData.result[index] == undefined`, which implies that the `adData.result` object has no key whose name is the value of `index`. You can print `Object.keys(adData.result)` and see what keys ARE viable in this object.

Comment: please see my updated question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```js
data = adData.result[index]
```

`adData.result` has only one element, while `index` may easily be greater than zero, as it is index of the address is address list.  If you need to save only one source file per smart contract, then change this line like this:

```js
data = adData.result[0]
```

If you need to save all the source files, do something like this:

```js
adData.result.forEach (data => {
  contractName = data.ContractName; // for first address its OK, if adresses are given one by one then still its OK, but for loop its not OK...

  compVersion = data.CompilerVersion;
  sourceCode = data.SourceCode;

  fs.writeFile('./openSourceContracts/'+contractName+'.sol', sourceCode, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Saved! contract'); // shows output Saved! contract... for the first contract only 
  });
});
```

Comment: You are perfect... thanks a lot .... again...